# Dismissing Modal View Swift

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift, modal-dialog, xcode6

EDIT: Thanks to the person behind the answer below, who fixed the unknown class. However, can anyone tell me if the code to dismiss is correct? I am on vacation and can't program until I get back.

I am developing an app in Swift. Currently, I am working on an info screen (legal notices, credits, documentation, etc)  that will be presented modally atop the main screen.

The expected behavior is that, when a button press triggers `Dismiss` in `InfoViewController`, the modal view controller is dismissed.

Here’s the code I’m trying to use:

```
//This is InfoViewController, the swift file used to conorol the info screen.

import UIKit

class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func Dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});//This is intended to dismiss the Info sceen.
        println("pressed")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Here’s the layout of the storyboards:

[image: postimg.org/image/wbozsmtr3/]

When I press the button, the app crashes and doesn’t dismiss the modal view controller.

It compiles, suggesting it is not a syntactual error.

Here’s the LLVM debugger output:

> 2014-08-30 20:02:20.571 CryptoCalc[799:244086] 17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
>   //Unrelated stuff deleted.
>   2014-08-30 20:03:03.756 CryptoCalc[799:244086] Unknown class InfoViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   2014-08-30 20:03:20.485 CryptoCalc[799:244086] -[UIViewController Dismiss:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d57990
>   2014-08-30 20:03:20.489 CryptoCalc[799:244086] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController Dismiss:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d57990'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2238be2f 0x2f46bc8b 0x22391179 0x2238f097 0x222c11f8 0x259b9fef 0x259b9f91 0x259a4d13 0x259b99fd 0x259b96d7 0x259b2fa1 0x25989a09 0x25bfbae3 0x259884a1 0x2235257f 0x2235198f 0x2234fff5 0x2229e611 0x2229e423 0x297f80a9 0x259e8485 0x73720 0x7375c 0x2f9f1aaf)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

If you need any more info, let me know. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is `Unknown class InfoViewController in Interface Builder file.`

You need to make sure that (in 'Custom Class' section)

1) The class in the storyboard is set to `InfoViewController`

2) The module is set to 'Current - your project name'

*screen shot include to show which part of Interface builder I am referring to*

[image]

Comment: Will try when I have a chance. Is the rest of the code (the code to dismiss the modal view) correct?